# php-fpm: settings in mods-available/xdebug.ini have no effect

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to apply custom xdebug settings via editing mods-available/xdebug.ini but when I restart php-fpm there are only the default settings applied. There are no related errors in the error logs visible.

What could be the reason that the custom settings are not applied?

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
#The default port 9000 doesn’t work as some other service (don’t remember which one) is using it as well
xdebug.remote_port=10000

#phpstorm's xdebug validate tool suggests:
#xdebug.remote_host=172.27.0.1
#but it's not working
#on mac you have to use this for docker
#xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost
#or (is the more recent one):
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
#more info:
#https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000229624-Setting-up-xDebug-with-PHPUnit-using-Docker-for-Mac-and-PHPStorm
#https://devilbox-test.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/enable-xdebug.html
#https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds


xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name=xdebug-profile-cachegrind.out-%H-%R
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to find out which modules are enabled via the php-cli command "php -m"
I got a list of enabled modules but also an error message right above the list:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini on line 5
```

Which points out that the # character isn't interpreted as the start of a comment. So after a short googling I've found out that one has to use semicolons to mask comments within ini files:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
;The default port 9000 doesn’t work as some other service  (don’t remember which one)  is using it as well
xdebug.remote_port=10000

;phpstorm's xdebug validate tool suggests:
;xdebug.remote_host=172.27.0.1
;but it's not working
;on mac you have to use this for docker
;xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost
;or  (is the more recent one):
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
;more info:
;https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000229624-Setting-up-xDebug-with-PHPUnit-using-Docker-for-Mac-and-PHPStorm
;https://devilbox-test.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/enable-xdebug.html
;https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds


xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name=xdebug-profile-cachegrind.out-%H-%R
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```